# Small database recommendation (free)

Tags: database

I need a small database for handling some stuff ... nothing too big, up to let's say 1000 entries.

Problem is the last time I used a database of some kind, was round', oh I don't know, 1995 ... dBase, version unknown, under DOS.

What is there on the market today, that is roundabout in that league: small, fast, it's really be swell if it was free, but I won't insist on that.

*I just went through dBase's [website](http://www.dbase.com/) (wow, they still exist) but it doesn't seem they have any kind of free version.*

*p.s. I'd really like to try to avoid any kind of "programming" in that area. The simpler, the better.*

Comment: What do you need this for?

Comment: @musicfreak - i explained it some more here: http://superuser.com/questions/111823/is-this-data-appropriate-for-keeping-in-a-database

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[sqlite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) might be the answer, with a suitable front end. It is a SLIGHT abuse of it, but in a good way

Comment: Why/what do you mean under "slight abuse" ... I'm not into databases, so some hidden meaning probably escapes me ...

Comment: If I understood correctly, sqlite is a whole (minus the frontend - btw, I don't mind the command line interface, quite the opposite :) database. I don't need anything else to use it and save my data in a file, right ? I know these may be overly simple questions, but I'd appreciate all the help you can give on the subject.

Comment: sqlite is generally meant to be used embedded as part of a app - you're using tools meant to edit or create databased which later get incorperated into an app. However, it seems quite perfect considering what you seem to want. You'd need to know some basic sql to do stuff over cli- and that's pretty close to programming, so i was looking for GUIs.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps try Open Office Base http://www.openoffice.org/product/base.html

Comment: I'll try it ... hardly small, but at least they're free :-)

Answer (score 1):

SQLite for small apps, MySQL for bigger ones.

Comment: Well, it is small :) And free :) Apart from the documentation available next to the download section, do you perchance know of some tutorial for this kind of databases (assume no previous knowledge <-- this doesn't look like anything like dBase ... as I remember it)

Comment: If I understood correctly, sqlite is a whole (minus the frontend) database. I don't need anything else to use it and save my data in a file, right ? I know these may be overly simple questions, but I'd appreciate all the help you can give on the subject.

Comment: Relational databases may not be the best for this situation. Yes, you can avoid programming with a good enough front-end, but I think it's just overkill. @Idigas: Yes, SQLite is all you need if you want to go into that direction.

Comment: if you wanted mysql, you could probably use the cli, phpmyadmin or adminer to work on it. Without knowing more though, sqlite sounds like the best bet.

Answer (score 0):

I think Kexi is what you looking for.

http://www.kexi-project.org/